# Installation Hadoop 2.7.0 on windows 32 bits

Tags: maven, hadoop

I've been trying to install Hadoop 2.7.0 on a windows 2008 server 32 bits service pack 2 on an IBM 365 server for the past 2 weeks.

I've followed the instructions given at http://bfeinsilver.blogspot.com.es/2014/03/installing-apache-hadoop-220-on-windows.html (**yes, I know that's for hadoop 2.2.0) and applied several patches obtained in many places.

I have protobuf version 2.5.0 correctly installed, Java JDK 1.8.0_45 and maven 3.3.3

I'm using the command mvn package -Pdist,native-win,docs -DskipTests -Dtar

The error is:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.7.0:prot oc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecut ionException: protoc failure -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you please provide the Exact error (log)details .

Comment: I actually installed proto 2.5.0 as it asked and now it says: [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.7.0:prot
oc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-common: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecut
ionException: protoc failure -> [Help 1]

Comment: Did you added the Protobuff classpath ???

Comment: I had not and thank you for reminding me. So I did and it is still stuck at the same point, now saying: [WARNING] [protoc, --java_out=(...)
to\ZKFCProtocol.proto] failed with error code 1
[ERROR] protoc compiler error

Comment: I think your protobuff didnt find "protoc"!! make sure that the correct protobuff packages are installed!!

Comment: Actually, the problem is that protoc was improperly built: even though the building process went ok and protoc --version worked, it only created a 30K file in comparison with the over 2K protoc file I downloaded and worked fine. Weird! Now the compilation is stuck at a new point

Comment: Now the error is at the HDFS compilation [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec retur
ned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="E:\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-p
roject\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 8:109 in E:\hadoop\ha
doop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml

Comment: cool !! its windows native issue. Open the Native library  "E:\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-p roject\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" build that project in Visual studio 2010 and start the build agian!!

Comment: Thanks, but I am building it from within a windows SDk 7.1 command window as indicated in the manual and by some people. Why now Visual Studio 2010?